# Are Concerns in Ruby on Rails replacement for service classes in MVC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, architecture

I am a newbie in Ruby on Rails. Coming from a C# and Java background, Ruby on Rails seems bizzare, yet interesting at the same time. It's almost like coming from a class-based object-oriented world to the prototyping concept of JavaScript, or even to a functional language.

Anyways, in a traditional C# or Java MVC application, I tend to keep my models and controllers as clean as possible, extracting the business logic into service classes. My models are just POCOs/POJOs (with some calculated fields and validation at most). And my controllers just process incoming requests (relying heavily on dependency injection) and then return a view or JSON.

Yet, I do not see any clear pattern in the RoR world. Some people tend to put all their business logic into controllers, some put it into models (with ActiveRecords, it kind of makes sense, although I don't like it).

And then there is the concept of Concerns. Are they the right place to extract my business logic, instead of using services? If yes, could you include an example of proper Concers use? I still struggle with the concept of modules (are they more of namespaces, or rather interfaces)? As said at the beginning, Ruby seems like a whole new galaxy to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say jpgeek reaction is part of the answer. The is a lot of movement towards service objects to clean up fat models or large controllers actions. Just create an app/services folder and create service classes like:

```
class TargetDestructionService

  def initialize(shooter, target)
    @shooter = shooter
    @target = target
  end


  def execute
    #Lot of code that causes the destruction of the target.
  end
end
```

Then in your model or controller you would call:

```
TargetDestructionService.new(EvilRobot.new, Human.new).execute
```

Here is a nice article about it: https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services

Answer (score 3):

This question could get into the weeds a bit as it brings in a lot of personal preferences.  However here is my take on it.

First, Concerns are not a replacement for Service classes.  Concerns are a clean and nifty way to manage your mix-ins.  If you are new to Ruby, mix-ins are basically a way of injecting instance and/or class methods into existing classes.  For example, given these classes:

```
class EvilRobot < ActiveRecord::Base
  def destroy(target)
    ...
  end
end

class OrneryTeenAger < ActiveRecord::Base
  def destroy(target)
    ...
  end
end
```

you could dry out the code with:

```
require 'active_support/concern'
module EvilTools
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def destroy(target)
      ...
    end
  end
end

class EvilRobot < ActiveRecord::Base
  include EvilTools
end

class OrneryTeenAger < ActiveRecord::Base
  include EvilTools
end
```

I think that the vast majority of Rails developers, myself included, go for a fat-model, thin controller design.  Just how fat though is a matter of taste.  I also tend to move functionality to classes under lib if they don't fit logically within a model, or extract into an engine or gem.